# Bluescreen 0x00000101 when installing "Silverlight 4 Tools for VS 2010" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install the IIS Smooth Streaming client through Web Platform Installer. It has a dependency on the Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 though, so Web Platform Installer started installing it first. In mid install I got an error that my RAM memory is full! I had a lot of browser tabs open (many of them flash... Chrome really took a lot of it) so I went over to close the browser. Before I could even do that, though, the computer crashed (no bluescreen) and restarted.

Afterwards I retried installing the Smooth Streaming Client. It starts the installation, goes 10 seconds into it, then the system halts (everything stops dead in it's tracks) and goes over to a bluescreen. There's no written explanation, only this hexadecimal error number: 0x00000101. This always happens now, no metter how often I try.

System information:

```
Sandybridge Intel Core i5 2500k
8 GB DDR3 Ram
Page file deactivated (Thus the RAM error the first time. YES I FILLED 8 GB OF RAM)
Asus P8P67
Anything else? Do tell!
```

EDIT: Tried to install it directly using the file now. Somewhere along the last part of the setup it bluescreens. This time it restarted instantly. Googling has given me hints like "race conditions" that result in the bluescreens.

The direct download is here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177508

I tried installing the Smooth Streaming Client from the file, too, and it said something about an unfinished MSI installation... MSI tried to finalize it and threw error 2906 (script header?) Afterwards the Smooth Streaming Client was installed. Still the Silverlight 4 Tools are considered not installed by MSI and "officially" installing it will result in a blue one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your install of Silverlight. The fact that you were installing Silverlight is unrelated to the fact that your system bugchecked, and it has nothing to do with a race-condition.

The bugcheck code is 0x101 which is CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT - an error that is most commonly caused by overclocking your system. If you have overclocked your system, you should undo that change now.

Comment: My system is never overclocked :)

Comment: You might need to get a new motherboard then

Comment: yeah, I will... I have been having problems with virtualization too.